# Type declaration error despite adding .d.ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using a npm package called `update-immutable` which happens to not have a typescript definition available built in or by `@types`. So I created a type definition file in my project and now VS Code detects the proper types for this package.

However with `noImplicitAny` option set to true, Angular's compiler doesn't seem to detect this type definition file and will throw an error `Could not find a declaration file for module 'update-immutable'. '.../node_modules/update-immutable/dist/update.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

How can I get Angular's compiler to find the `.d.ts` type definition that I created for the npm package that I am using?

I did find out through enabling `traceResolution` that if I put the `update-immutable.d.ts` file directly under the project root it will detect it. But I would like to keep these type files organized and not littered under the project root if possible.

Project tree:

```
projectroot
+ src
| + app
| | + states
| |   + core
| |     + core.reducer.ts (where update-immutable is imported)
| + types
|   + update-immutable
|     + index.d.ts (type file created by me)
+ node_modules
| + update-immutable
|   + ...
+ tsconfig.json
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "jszip": [
        "node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"
      ]
    },
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

`index.d.ts` type definition:

```
declare module 'update-immutable' {
  export default function update<T>(view: T, upd: object): T;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `files` to `true` in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @MátéSolymosi I don't think that's a valid value for `files`. I believe it requires an array of strings.

Comment: My bad, sorry, I was confusing it with the `files` option of `ts-node` 

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Angular but had this issue with another project.

My issue was that I needed to set both `paths` and `typeRoots` in my `tsconfig.json` file. Here's an example I referenced from [andyperlitch/typeroots-fail](https://github.com/andyperlitch/typeroots-fail):

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./custom-types"],
  "paths": {
    "*": ["*", "./custom-types/*"]
  }
}
```

See a [larger discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22217#issuecomment-751904666).